# Remove suffix icon from DropdownSearch in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dropdown

I want to remove suffix icon from DropdownSearch widget. I am using [dropdown_search](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search) plugin.
I have tried giving size to icon and also added visibility false. but any of these didn't work.
Even I have tried using dropdown builder too..!!

Please help..!!

```
DropdownSearch<String>(
      dropdownBuilder: (context, str) {
        return Text(str ?? "-");
      },
      dropdownDecoratorProps: DropDownDecoratorProps(
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
          dropdownSearchDecoration: _appTheme.dropDownDecoration()),
      dropdownButtonProps: const DropdownButtonProps(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          icon: SizedBox(
            width: 0,
            child: Visibility(
                visible: false,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_downward,
                  size: 0,
                )),
          ),
          isVisible: false,
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 0, maxHeight: 0),
          iconSize: 0),
      popupProps: PopupProps.menu(
        textStyle: _appTheme.textFiledStyle,
        showSelectedItems: true,
        showSearchBox: true,
      ),
      items: _registrationBloc.countries,
      onChanged: (value) {
        _registrationBloc.selectedCountry = value;
      },
      selectedItem: _registrationBloc.selectedCountry,
    )
```

Comment: have you checked the third party plugin code which you are using? whether it has some default settings or not?

Comment: I have checked. they are using IconButton. that's why may be iconSize property is not working.

Comment: yes in that case you have options like not to use the plugin or modify the plugin code for your use

Comment: Okay Thank you.. Is there any other plugin you can suggest?

Comment: not sure about your requirements.

Comment: I just want searchable dropdown without suffix icon.

Comment: that you can check know! but my suggestion creating own widget by yourself

Answer (score 0):

set the isVisible property to false it will work.
or you can use other plugin. one is [searchfield](https://pub.dev/packages/searchfield) which i have used.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'dropDownButton' property for DropdownSearch, use it as follows

```
dropDownButton : Container(),
```

hope it works